# azure function v4 is not detected by default by vs 2022 for mac

Tags: visual-studio-mac, azure-functions-core-tools

I have installed Azure funciton v4 and ie the default runtime for the azure function core tools. But while debugging the azure funciton using VS 2022 for Mac it is starting the azure function v3 and while looking at the source it seems it is using different azure CLI from addins come with part of visual studio 2022. Anyway we can select our own version of azure function runtime like how VS code provides instead of relying on VS 2022 mac provided azure function is not latest ?

VS 2022 for windows is taking care of this automatically if I specify below in csproj, expecting the same from VS 2022 for ma

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

In the logs I can see that VS for Mac is trying to load different Azure CLI :  '/Applications/Visual Studio (Preview).app/Contents/MonoBundle/AddIns/MonoDevelop.AzureFunctions/azure-functions-cli/

It is bad that Visual Studio is not upto date with Azure Function core run times and hence it should have some feature like VS Code to choose whichever azure function run time.

Comment: VSMac22 is incredibly poor and my whole team is having this issue. I have just paid for Rider and all Azure functions work perfectly out of the box. Its insane that Rider can run Microsofts products better than Microsoft. I have also tried running the command suggested in the docs to make sure it uses v4 `brew link --overwrite azure-functions-core-tools@4` but it did nothing.